# Why is it necessary to declare a field as final when to be used in an inner class?

Tags: java, field, anonymous-inner-class

Why do we have to declare a field in a class or method to be final in java,

if it is to be accessed/used from an anonymous inner class?

Comment: You don't need that. The only thing you need are getters and setters (a very important way of manipulating field in Java, take a look !). Final means you will never be able to change its value.

Comment: Lutzi is correct.  This restriction applies to local variables, not fields.

Comment: Also note that this is not needed anymore, it is enough if the local variable is effectively final.